# Car rental in Ireland for under-25 driver

Tags: car-rentals, road-trips, ireland

I am going to Dublin in a month and would like to rent a car there in order to be able to make a little road trip around Ireland. I am 24 years old and my friend is 23. I have seen here
[Renting a car in Ireland when under 25?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13128/renting-a-car-in-ireland-when-under-25) that it is not possible to rent a car in Ireland when younger than 25 years old or, if it is possible, it is very pricey.

Are other alternatives for me to book a car at the cheapest price in Ireland? I know in my country we have websites that allow people to rent cars from individuals. Is there a similar service in Dublin and, if so, would they accept me being 24 years old ?

**EDIT 6th of October**

I am mostly looking for car rental websites between individuals in Ireland now as you showed in the comments it was not possible to rent a car under 25 years old without the young driver fee.

Comment: I would rent a car for 10 days.I haven't seen that much companies willing to accept your drivers and if they do they charge additional fees. If the charge is 30 euros per week for the car, the additional fees for young driver is 30euros per day which brings the total fee at 330 euros for the duration of the trip excluding additional insurance. In addition to that they take a bigger security deposit of 1200 euros. For the distance it would be around 100 to 300 km per day.. I would like to find a way not to pay this additional 300 euros for that trip and to avoid such a big deposit.

Comment: I just went on Sixt and it says **Les conducteurs de moins de 26 ans peuvent uniquement conduire les catégories de voiture suivantes en s'acquittant d'un supplément de 30,00 EUR par jour: MBMN, MCMN, EBMN, ECAN, ECAE, ECMN, EDMN, CCAN, CCMN, CDAR, CDMN, IDAR, IDMN, IDMR.
Tous les catégories de véhicule non indiquées ne peuvent être loués au conducteur de moins de 26 ans.** which means 30 euros per day

Comment: Yes.. Unfortunately it is not clear since even though I enter my age it does not calculate additional fees... I have to go through terms and conditions and they are not very transparent either on that.

Comment: Most car rental companies add a daily surcharge for young drivers. There's no way around it.

Comment: "Most" but what I'm asking is which ones don't surcharge them or if there is another system in place for renting cars from individuals

Comment: Alternatively: Hitchhike. That's what I did a few months back, and what most all the other backpackers did as well (unless they were taking buses, which take forever.)

Comment: The problem is that we would like to go to pretty remote places... Otherwise we would have taken the buss. I don't want to rely on the odds of finding a driver that would be in for taking us for a ride

Comment: I don't personally know of any, but companies with just a few cars are your best bet, if any. Go to your favourite maps app and look for car rentals around the places you can possibly pick the car up. Phone up each of them and ask.

Comment: The good news is, some car hire comparison sites allow you to enter your age and it then shows only eligible companies, for example [EasyCar](https://www.easycar.com/en/car-hire/ireland). The bad news is, I tried it out and EasyCar seem to think Sixt are the *only* major car hire company listed for Dublin that allow under 25s. It also *doesn't* include age surcharges in the listed price quotes. If Sixt with the surcharge are too expensive, I'd try looking for smaller local independent car hire companies, or maybe trying carshare like [blablacar](https://www.blablacar.co.uk/search-car-sharing)

Answer (score 4):

I traveled in Ireland in 2011, at the age of 24 (and with a French driving license like you). I rented a car at "Budget" (online reservation on their website www.budget.ie) and didn't have to pay a young driver additional fee.

Try to check if it is still the case. FYI the price was 78€ for 4 and a half days, for an Economic 2 door, in november.

I quickly checked their terms and conditions, just got a doubt about a sentence, maybe the best option is to email them at reservations@budget.ie

Comment: Merci Nicolas. I'm gonna check it up ASAP, cause my trip is in a couple of weeks and I don't wish to rent a bike for my tour of Ireland :)

Comment: De rien. You should double check yes, but at that time at least it was possible (I never rent car without being covered). Ask directly through the ".ie" site or their email address, not through the French site of Budget ;)

I had the same problems for drivers surcharge during many trips, it's a lot of time lost to find the right agency. For example in the US, the surcharge may depend on the state where you are renting...

Comment: I lived in the USA for a while and was able to find places to rent cars without young driver fees. This is why I find it weird it is not the same in Ireland.

Comment: @MopMop: did you got the feedback from Budget?

Comment: No, but I have booked through them and there was no additional fees on the website that I have used or on the terms of sales. So I guess I will see what happens thursday !

Comment: Let us know, and have a good trip!

Comment: In the end, Budget does not even accept under 25 year old drivers... So when we got there the reservation was canceled :'(

Comment: :-/ they changed their policy since 2011